# Remove a link from an embedded video

Tags: html

I have an embedded video on my web page. How do I stop the embedded video from linking to another webpage when it's clicked? The embeded video is not from youtube or vimeo.

This is the simple code:

```
<iframe   src="http://flashservice.simple.com/embedframe/18558608" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the I-Frame a CSS property of `pointer-events: none;`. Note that this doesn't work in IE < 11.